# Convert string to double or float c#

Tags: c#, double, string-conversion

I need to convert a string to double. Or float, whatever suits best for this type of conversion.

The string is "25.00".

How would I convert this string so that I can use it in calculations?

I've tried with:

```
string s1 = "2";
string s2 = "25.00";

double d1 = Convert.ToDouble(s1);
double d2 = Convert.ToDouble(s2);
double d3 = d2 * d1;
```

I've also tried with this:

```
string s1 = "2";
string s2 = "25.00";

double d1 = double.Parse(s1);
double d2 = double.Parse(s2);
double d3 = d2 * d1;
```

And:

```
string s1 = "2";
string s2 = "25.00";

float f1 = float.Parse(s1);
float f2 = float.Parse(s2);
float f3 = f2 * f1;
```

None of this seem to work, I get a formatexception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect your default culture info uses comma as a decimal separator instead of dot. If you know your input will have a dot, it's best to specify the invariant culture explicitly:

```
double d1 = double.Parse(s1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
double d2 = double.Parse(s2, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

However, if the *decimal* values matter, you should consider using `decimal` instead of either `float` or `double`:

```
decimal d1 = decimal.Parse(s1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
decimal d2 = decimal.Parse(s2, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you get a format exception, that means that the culture you are running your code on does not use the `.` character for its decimal separator. There are several things you can do:

1. Change your global culture to one that uses the `.` character as its decimal separator
2. Manually replace the `.` character with your culture's decimal separator
3. Call an overload of the various parse methods that takes in an `IFormatProvider` instance

I consider the third option to be the best by far. It lets you specify what format the parse method expects. The `CultureInfo` class implements the `IFormatProvider` interface. In your code, you expect the `.` character to be the decimal separator. This is true in several cultures, but your safest choice is probably the `InvariantCulture`.

You can modify your code then as follows:

```
string s1 = "2"; 
string s2 = "25.00";

double d1 = Convert.ToDouble(s1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
double d2 = Convert.ToDouble(s2, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
double d3 = d2 * d1;
```

```
string s1 = "2";
string s2 = "25.00";

double d1 = double.Parse(s1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
double d2 = double.Parse(s2, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
double d3 = d2 * d1;
```

```
string s1 = "2";
string s2 = "25.00";

float f1 = float.Parse(s1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
float f2 = float.Parse(s2, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
float f3 = f2 * f1;
```

Here, the `CultureInfo` class' `NumberFormat` property is used to determine the decimal separator used when parsing the string to a `double` or `float`.

I have created a .NET Fiddle to show you that it works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z5HB4T

You can see what the decimal separator is for a specific culture by using the `NumberDecimalSeparator` property of the `CultureInfo`'s `NumberFormat` property:

```
// Returns: "."
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;

// Outputs: "."
new CultureInfo("en-US").NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;

// Returns: ","
new CultureInfo("nl-NL").NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;

// Returns: "<depends on what is set as the current culture>"
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
```

See it in action at: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nSbYoP

What is interesting, is that the `NumberFormat` property is of type `NumberFormatInfo` which also implements `IFormatProvider`! This means that you could also pass a `NumberFormatInfo` instance to the parse methods. This allows you to create a number format fully to your liking. We could then use any decimal number separator string we like. The following examples changes the decimal number separator to the `#` character:

```
var numberFormatInfo = new NumberFormatInfo();
numberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator = "#";

string s1 = "2"; 
string s2 = "25#00";

double d1 = Convert.ToDouble(s1, numberFormatInfo);
double d2 = Convert.ToDouble(s2, numberFormatInfo);
double d3 = d2 * d1;
```

See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/h6ex2Z

This approach gives your total freedom on how you want the parse methods to interpret numbers.

Comment: @clark-kim No problem. I have added some more information that might be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes when you convert for example the string "4.1" to double the conversion will gives you 41, for that you can easy fix replacing the "." with ","
ej:
double ress = Convert.toDouble("4.1".replace(".",",");